# What exactly does this CSS selector with a comma match?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a question about CSS selectors.

In my CSS file I have the following code:

```
.table_legenda th, td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #76818a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #76818a;
    border-left: 1px solid #76818a;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Exactly what elements does that select?

I thought that it should select all the `th` and `td` elements *inside* a `table` having the class `table_legenda`.

However, when I test it, the style also gets applied to `td` elements inside other tables that do *not* have the `table_legenda` class (but do have another class).

Why does that happen? What am I missing?

Comment: you need to use this selector : `.table_legenda th, .table_legenda td`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the precedence of the comma.

```
.table_legenda th, td {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
.table_legenda th {}
td {}
```

and **not** to:

```
.table_legenda th {}
.table_legenda td {}
```

---

You need to specify the complete selector each time you have a comma:

```
.table_legenda th,
.table_legenda td {}
```

---

A preprocessing tool such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) can give you alternative syntax:

```
.table_legenda {
    th, td {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it selects `tr inside table_legenda class` , **and** in addition to that, all `td`.

The selector you want is

```
.table_legenda th, .table_legenda td
```

In this one, it selects all the `th inside .table_legenda` and all `td inside .table_legenda`

Answer (score -2):

The , means selecting another attribute so what you should do is:

```
.table_legenda th,.table_legenda td {
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
font-weight: bold;
color: #76818a;
border-bottom: 1px solid #76818a;
border-left: 1px solid #76818a;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
```